# How add ontology to `virtuoso-sparql-endpoint-quickstart`?

Tags: virtuoso, openlink-virtuoso

I'm new to Docker's world. I want to query an ontology locally. I have already configured
[virtuoso-sparql-endpoint-quickstart](https://github.com/dbpedia/virtuoso-sparql-endpoint-quickstart).
It works, and my endpoint is  http://localhost:8890/sparql.

Now I want to query my own ontology (not DBpedia). So can I still use the same endpoint? How can I add my ontology to virtuoso?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that an *ontology* is a vocabulary used to describe one or more classes of entities.  The descriptions themselves are typically referred to as *instance data*, and queries are usually run over such instance data.  (There are a few ontologies used to describe ontologies, and *these* descriptions are also instance data, and queries might be made against them.)

There are [a number of ways to load data into Virtuoso](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtRDFInsert).  The most useful for most people is the [Bulk Load facility](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtBulkRDFLoader).  For most purposes, you'll want to load your data into one or more distinct Named Graphs, such that queries can be scoped to one, some, or all of the those Named Graphs.

Any and all queries can be made against the same `http://localhost:8890/sparql` endpoint.  Results will vary depending on the Named Graphs identified in your query.